# EF CTP4: For Code Only, no database generation needed, how much DB info is needed?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-relationship, ado.net-entity-data-model

I have a database, and I have entity POCO's, and all I want to use EF for is to map between the two and keep track of changes for loading, saving, etc.

I have been reading a lot of the literature (such as it is) on "Code First", and I am unclear on how much of the database information I need to supply when there is not going to be a database generated.

For example, does EF need to know which properties are keys, the maximum length of string properties, the relationships between the tables, etc.? Or if it does need to know, can it get that information from the database itself? In other words, do I have to provide [Key] annotations and such, or provide configuration information detailing the foreign-key relationships, if no database needs to be created?

UPDATE: To make things a little clearer, the following code is what I am talking about. I have to manually create this class derived from DbContext. I could supply a lot of DB information about the properties in OnModelCreating, or in attributes attached to the properties in the entity classes.

```
    public class SchedulerContext : DbContext
    {
    public SchedulerContext(EntityConnection connection)
        : base(connection)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Client> Clients { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ConsultantDistrict> ConsultantDistricts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ConsultantInterviewSetting> ConsultantInterviewSettings { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ConsultantUnavailable> ConsultantsUnavailable { get; set; }
    public DbSet<CustomEmailTemplate> CustomEmailTemplates { get; set; }
    public DbSet<DateEvent> DateEvents { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Event> Events { get; set; }
    public DbSet<EventItem> EventItems { get; set; }
    public DbSet<EventItemUserViewed> EventItemsUserViewed { get; set; }
    public DbSet<FlaggedDate> FlaggedDates { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Interview> Interviews { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Interviewee> Interviewees { get; set; }
    public DbSet<IntervieweeNote> IntervieweeNotes { get; set; }
    public DbSet<InterviewEvent> InterviewEvents { get; set; }
    public DbSet<NotificationSent> NotificationsSent { get; set; }
    public DbSet<SchedulerRole> SchedulerRoles { get; set; }
    public DbSet<SiteEvent> SiteEvents { get; set; }
    public DbSet<UnavailableHour> UnavailableHours { get; set; }
    public DbSet<UserLogin> UserLogins { get; set; }
    public DbSet<UserSites> UserSites { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Visit> Visits { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<ConsultantUnavailable>().MapSingleType().ToTable("ConsultantsUnavailable");
        modelBuilder.Entity<EventItemUserViewed>().MapSingleType().ToTable("EventItemsUserViewed");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the EF *does* need information on `string` field lengths, foreign keys, etc., in the model. For example, if a DB FK has a cascade, the EF needs to know that so that it doesn't force you to manually delete detail records; if the EF is aware of the cascade it will let the DB handle that. Similarly, if the EF is aware that a key is store-generated (e.g., auto-incremented), it won't complain when you don't set it on a new record, because it will presume that the DB will do that.

However, the code-only approach takes a "convention over configuration" approach. You don't have to specify values which the EF can guess. [You can read about those here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2010/06/01/conventions-for-code-first.aspx).

If you are doing Code Only, the EF doesn't look at the DB at all when creating the model.

There is no way to tell the EF to look at code *and* the DB to create the model. You have to choose one or the other.

Comment: I understand. I'm not talking about using EF to create the model from the database. But I do supply a connection string to the context object. It does have to know something about the database in order to save data. I'm just wondering if it needs to know EVERYTHING (keys, relationships, etc.) if it is not going to create the database.

Comment: On further reading, it seems that maybe you do have to supply everything to the context object, because you have to recreate in memory all the data that is normally supplied in XML in the EDMX file. But I'm not sure about that ... stay tuned.

Comment: I have updated my post to include the code that's the focus of my concern.

Comment: Thank you Craig, that's exactly the kind of information I was looking for! (BTW I was aware of the code-only conventions, but they seemed a little daunting re foreign keys. Then I started wondering if needed them at all.)